# Elementwise sum of matrices in cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization, cell-array

I have a cell array as follows:

```
A = { [1 2;3 4] ;[5 6;7 8]};
```

How can I add

```
A{1,1} + A{2,1} = {[6 8;10 12]};
```

without a loop in Matlab?

Comment: @abbas have a look at my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cell array has size `2`, you can simply do:

```
result = plus(A{:});
```

This calls `plus` (addition) on the [comma-separated list](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) generated from the two-element cell array.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every entry of the cell array has the same dimension, you need to **con[`cat`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html)enate** them into the third dimension and [**`sum`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) them up afterwards:

```
%// concatenate along third dimension
B = cat(3, A{:})
%// sum along third dimension
C = sum(B,3)
```